# Nativescript Vue: List data getting jumbled on top of each other

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a list of data and when it renders, it's rendering on top of each other.  The data is a fairly long list of objects and I am using multiple fields.  I made a playground example by reducing the data list size and only using field (`display_name`) and it's still happening.
It seems to happen in random spots of the list but I am unsure as to how to resolve or more importantly, why it's happening.  I thought it may have had to do with my `key` not being unique but I made sure it was and it's still happening.  I included a playground and added screenshots.  Any ideas?

[Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=T4yASC)

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBgeu.jpg)

EDIT: (Adding Template)

```
<RadListView
    for="(movie,index) in this.movies" 
    ref="listView"
    @loaded="onListLoaded($event)"
    @itemTap="onItemTap($event)"
    itemHeight="50"
    :key="index"
    gridSpanCount=1
>
    <v-template>
        <FlexboxLayout class="item-row" :key='`flex` + index' flexDirection="row" width="100%" height="100%" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Stacklayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Image :key='`img-flag` + index' marginTop="-22" class="flag-image" marginBottom="-22" :src="movie.image" height="100%" />
                <Label :key='`display-name` + index' :text="movie.display_name" />
            </Stacklayout>
            <Image :key='`heart-1` + index' @tap="handleToggleFavorite(movie)" width="20" :src="movie.favorite ? heartFilled : heartUnfilled" />
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

Comment: Is it iOS specific?

Comment: @Manoj that I am not sure of.  I am only aiming for iOS and don't have NS setup for Android emulation.

Comment: I think the issue is with your layout, it looks better when I remove all the unwanted attributes / views - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=T4yASC&v=2. Obviously you may have a requirement for template with image etc., so if you could share what your template looks like, it's easier to suggest a better / cleaner layout to meet your requirements.

Comment: thanks @Manoj.  Added template as an edit above. I'm curious as to why it acts fine with a small amount of data but gets wonky when the array of objects is large.  I initially had only 10 objects in the array and it was fine but when I used my full set of data (around 150), that is when it started rendering strangely

Comment: I have upto 5k items loaded at a time, it works well. It depends on your layout. I saw your layout code already in Playground and I had no clue why you had to do negative margin and all, which is why I did ask you to show the expected results, possibly an image how the list view should look like.

Comment: @Manoj got it, sorry.  Here is a screenshot of how the list should look ( https://imgur.com/a/3ZYaOpW )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your mockup, I think you can achieve it with a simple GridLayout.

```
<v-template>
    <GridLayout columns="auto,*,auto" class="list-group-item">
        <Image col="0" :src="movie.image"
            class="m-5 thumb img-circle">
        </Image>
        <Label col="1" :text="movie.display_name"></Label>
        <Image col="2" src="path_to_icon" class="thumb">
        </Image>
    </GridLayout>
</v-template>
```

Comment: yep, looks like it works when I use a cleaner template like this.  Thanks!

Comment: hey @Manoj -- It actually looks like it's still happening when filtering the data and then clearing the search box to show the original list.  ( https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=WoYvyi&v=1 ) .  I made a new playground to keep it clean and to the point, using your template and filtering the data as described in the `Radlistview` API doc

Comment: You had made a lot of changes, especially I'm not sure why you are using `*` in column for images when you have given them fixed width, also why horizontal alignment when you have them aligned in column already. Moreover you are not suppose to use ListView inside StackLayout. Please go through https://www.nslayouts.com/ to learn more about layouts.